# Hide Static Block from Category View on Layer Nav Click

Tags: layered-navigation, static-block

When I setup a category page I can set it to display products, a static block or both.  I would like to display a static block but when any option in the layered nav is clicked, I would like to hide the static block and only display the products.

Comment: Are you click on layered nav category?